# This code does not count me the word i type

Tags: javascript

```js
var tweet = prompt("Compose your tweet:");
var tweetCount = prompt.length;
alert("You've written " + tweetCount + " characters, you've " + (140 - tweetCount) + " characters left.");
```

Comment: You should check the length of tweet instead of prompt, use `tweet.length`

Comment: @Olian04 granted. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Typo at line 2 : -`prompt.length`- instead of `tweet.length`

```js
    var tweet = prompt("Compose your tweet:");
    var tweetCount = tweet.length;
    alert("You've written " + tweetCount + " characters, you've " + (140- tweetCount) + " characters left." );
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `tweet.length` not `prompt.length`.

```js
var tweet = prompt("Compose your tweet:");
var tweetCount = tweet.length;
alert("You've written " + tweetCount + " characters, you've " + (140 - tweetCount) + " characters left.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change `prompt` to `tweet` in the second line of your code because you are saving the input to `tweet`

Instead of `var tweetCount = prompt.length;` use `var tweetCount = tweet.length`

So now, your code becomes:

```
var tweet = prompt("Compose your tweet:");

var tweetCount = tweet.length;

alert("You've written " + tweetCount + " characters, you've " + (140- tweetCount) + " characters left." );
```